# Puppeteer not respecting timeout in Page.waitForFunction

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have while loop in [`Page.waitForFunction`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforfunction), but Puppeteer doesn't respect it. It just goes through returning `undefined`. Any possible reason for that?

```
 await page.waitForFunction(async () => {
    
    let iterations = 7
    while(!window.hasOwnProperty('__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__') && iterations > 0){
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
      iterations--
    }
    
    return !!(window.hasOwnProperty('__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__'))
  },{
    timeout: 10000
  })
```

Even if I return literal `true` value instead it still shows `undefined`.

Comment: It might be executed before the page has finished loading. Please check that the function is executed only after the page has loaded completely.

Comment: @HiteshPadhara yes, it does. When I add plain `setTimeout` without loop it actually waits and it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

`waitForFunction` is similar to `waitForSelector` in that it's a convenience wrapper on a common `evaluate` pattern, setting up a loop with `requestAnimationFrame` or a `MutationObserver`, then resolving when the loop ends.

As such, adding a second inner loop inside of `waitForFunction` seems to miss the point that the code is already in an implicit loop. The idea is that you simply put the condition into the `waitForFunction` callback and let it do the rest.

If you want to throttle the speed of the loop, either switch to `{polling: "mutation"}` or write your own `waitForFunction` using `evaluate` that uses the polling speed that best fits your use case. Since no mutation may correspond to this variable on the window, you'll probably have to use the second option.

I don't have your actual site, so I can only offer a hint of how you might implement this, but you'll probably want something like:

```js
await page.waitForFunction(
  `window.hasOwnProperty('__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__')`,
  {timeout: 10_000}
);
```

or if you can assume the variable that's attached is truthy:

```js
const handle = await page.waitForFunction(
  "window.__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__",
  {timeout: 10_000}
);
```

Complete, runnable example:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  __VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = {};
}, 5_000);
</script>
</body></html>
`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.setContent(html);
  // or for a normal use case:
  // await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

  const handle = await page.waitForFunction(
    "window.__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__",
    {timeout: 10_000}
  );
  console.log(handle);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

If you want to poll every second, you might try:

```js
const hook = await page.evaluate(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    const hook = window.__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__;

    if (hook) {
      return hook;
    }

    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  }
});
```

This effectively reimplements `waitForFunction` with a custom slow polling time rather than a tight 60 frames per second RAF. It quits after 7 tries and returns `undefined`. But probably this is not what you want, both because of speed and uglier code. You likely want to resolve as soon as that global is ready rather than waiting up to a second to see it appear, but I thought this would be instructive to show for comparison purposes.

We're also missing context for why you're waiting for this devtools hook, so it's always possible that this is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and there may be a better way to achieve whatever your underlying goal is.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. It made me drop it altogether, you're right - it was overdone. I stumbled upon slightly different problem if you may take a look: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9842